# AttributeError: module layoutparser has no attribute PaddleDetectionLayoutModel

Tags: python

AttributeError: module layoutparser has no attribute PaddleDetectionLayoutModel

I'm having this problem running paddleocr. What's wrong with this

```
import os
import cv2
from paddleocr import PPStructure,draw_structure_result,save_structure_res

table_engine = PPStructure(show_log=True)

save_folder = './output/table'
img_path = '../doc/table/1.png'
img = cv2.imread(img_path)
result = table_engine(img)
save_structure_res(result, save_folder,os.path.basename(img_path).split('.')[0])

for line in result:
    line.pop('img')
    print(line)

from PIL import Image

font_path = '../doc/fonts/simfang.ttf' # PaddleOCR下提供字体包
image = Image.open(img_path).convert('RGB')
im_show = draw_structure_result(image, result,font_path=font_path)
im_show = Image.fromarray(im_show)
im_show.save('result.jpg')
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! please post your full code and error message.

Comment: this is the code